# quick contact badge cannot passed the Intent by using Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI) startActivityForResult(i 0)

Tags: android, sdk

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;
    //FrameLayout fl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent contactpicker=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(contactpicker, 0);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                Uri contactUri = data.getData();
                FrameLayout badgeLargeHolder = (FrameLayout)
                findViewById(R.id.badge_holder_large);
                QuickContactBadge badgeLarge = new QuickContactBadge(this);
                badgeLarge.assignContactUri(contactUri);
                badgeLarge.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_LARGE);
                badgeLarge.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                badgeLargeHolder.addView(badgeLarge);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I got the error like this:
12-18 07:30:47.452: E/AndroidRuntime(657): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://contacts }

give any suggestion to resolve this Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` instead of `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`

```
Intent contactpicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                 ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
startActivityForResult(contactpicker, 0);
```

and also add this permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: :hey dude..can u please tell why i getting error in my code..what is the problem in my code...

Comment: @yogi : becuase Contacts.CONTENT_URI uri is deprecated in latest android API's

Comment: itz very usefull to me..may i know what android API's this will support and what android API you use

Comment: hey dude can u sent any android tutorial to my mailid: tamilms.nschool@gmail.com